# Insert output of query into another table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in Postgres 9.4. I have two tables:

```
                                      Table "public.parcel"
    Column    |          Type          |                            Modifiers
 ogc_fid      | integer                | not null default
 wkb_geometry | geometry(Polygon,4326) |
 county       | character varying      |
 parcel_area  | double precision       |

            Table "public.county"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers
--------+------------------------+-----------
 name   | character(1)           |
 chull  | geometry(Polygon,4326) |
 area   | double precision       |
```

I would like to find all the unique values of county in `parcel`, and the total areas of the attached parcels, and then insert them into the `county` table as `name` and `area` respectively.

I know how to do the first half of this:

```
SELECT county, 
       SUM(parcel_area) AS area 
FROM inspire_parcel 
GROUP BY county;
```

But what I don't know is how to insert these values into `county`. Can anyone advise?

I think it's something like:

```
UPDATE county SET name, area = (SELECT county, SUM(parcel_area) AS area 
FROM inspire_parcel GROUP BY county)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `INSERT INTO`. So, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO county
 SELECT county, SUM(parcel_area) AS area
  FROM inspire_parcel GROUP BY county;
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me when I edited it slightly: `INSERT INTO county(name, area)...`